# Problems with executing FFMPEG through PHP

Tags: php, exec

Have been trying to execute FFMPEG using a script I have uploaded to my domain

```
<?php
$output = array();
$result = -1;
exec('../../../../../../usr/bin/ffmpeg -ab 320k -i source.wav dest320.mp3', $output, $result);
var_dump($output, $result);
?>
```

The example code says the program should not be returning -1 unless there is an error but I have pointed to the exact path that FFMPEG is stored in.....

When I call 'ffmpeg -ab 320k -i source.wav dest320.mp3' from CentOS it works...

Am lost and have spent hte last few hours trying to work it out.

Thanks

CP

Comment: you do realize that you can use the absolute path, like: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` instead of going backwards into the directories, right ?  Also, you need to make sure the user under which you run `exec` has the right permissions to access ffmpeg.

Comment: What is the output when you run this?

Comment: Hey Twisted, no I didn't realise that, will try it now.  How can I check the user who runs exec has the right permissions?   Shark it outputs 

'array(0) { } int(-1)'

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have an exec that doesn't work in php, you should switch to passthru for debugging.

```
passthru('../../../../../../usr/bin/ffmpeg -ab 320k -i source.wav dest320.mp3 1 2>&1');
```

Appending 1 2>&1 to the end, pipes your stderr to stout, and returns any errors you have while running your exec.

Comment: I have just tried that and it didn't return anything at all.  Not sure what is up.....

Answer (score 0):

It is probably safer to use `passthru('/usr/bin/env ffmpeg -ab 320k -i source.wav dest320.mp3 1 2>&1');` which will get the correct path for ffmpeg without the need to specify and absolute/relative path.

Also worth noting that if you are using Ubuntu since 12.04, the `ffmpeg` command has been renamed to `avconv`.

Comment: Thanks mate, am using CentOS